# Extract commits related to code changes from commit tree

Tags: python, github, github-api, pygit2

Right now I am able to traverse through the commit tree for a github repository using pygit2 library. I am getting all the commits for each file change in the repository. This means that I am getting changes for text files with extensions .rtf as well in the repository. How do I filter out the commits which are related to code changes only? I don't want the changes related to text documents.

Appreciate any help or pointers. Thanks.

```
last = repo[repo.head.target]

t0=last

f = open(outputFile,'w')

print t0.hex


for commit in repo.walk(last.id):
     if t0.hex == commit.hex:
        continue

     print commit.hex
     out=repo.diff(t0,commit)
     f.write(out.patch)
     t0=commit;
```

As part of the output, I get the difference in rtf files as well as below:

```
diff --git a/archived-output/NEW/action-core[best].rtf b/archived-output/NEW/action-core[best].rtf
deleted file mode 100644
index 56cdec6..0000000
--- a/archived-output/NEW/action-core[best].rtf
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,8935 +0,0 @@
-{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\adeff31507\deff0\stshfdbch31506\stshfloch31506\stshfhich31506\stshfbi31507\deflang1033\deflangfe1033\themelang1033\themelangfe0\themelangcs0{\fonttbl{\f0\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\f1\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020b0604020202020204}Arial;}
-{\f2\fbidi \fmodern\fcharset0\fprq1{\*\panose 02070309020205020404}Courier New;}{\f3\fbidi \froman\fcharset2\fprq2{\*\panose 05050102010706020507}Symbol;}
```

Either I have to filter the commits from the tree or I have to filter the output . I was thinking if I could remove the changes related to rtf files by removing the corresponding commits while walking through the tree.

Comment: Can you update the post with what your current code looks like to do this? IMO, this is too broad as it stands now.

Comment: @mu無 I have added the details .

Comment: Remember that a commit can (and often does) involve more than a single file, so simply "removing the corresponding commits" is probably the wrong solution.  I suspect you have to iterate through the tree object attached to each commit and look for modified files, and then pick the ones you want.

Comment: @larsks yes. If that is possible, how do we get the list of modified files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If that is possible, how do we get the list of modified files?

Ah, now you're asking the right questions!  Git, of course, does not store a list of modified files in each commit.  Rather, each commit represents the state of the entire repository at a certain point in time.  In order to find the modified files, you need to compare the files contained in one commit with the previous commit.

For each commit returned by `repo.walk()`, the `tree` attribute refers to the associated `Tree` object (which is itself a list of `TreeEntry` objects representing files and directories contained in that particular `Tree`).

A `Tree` object has a `diff_to_tree()` method that can be used to compare it against another `Tree` object.  This returns a `Diff` object, which acts as an iterator over a list of `Patch` objects.  Each `Patch` object refers to the changes in a single file between the two `Tree`s that are being compared.

The `Patch` object is really the key to all this, because this is how
we determine which files have been modified.

The following code demonstrates this.  For each commit, it will print
a list of new, modified, or deleted files:

```
import stat
import pygit2


repo = pygit2.Repository('.')

prev = None
for cur in repo.walk(repo.head.target):

    if prev is not None:
        print prev.id
        diff = cur.tree.diff_to_tree(prev.tree)
        for patch in diff:
            print patch.status, ':', patch.new_file_path,
            if patch.new_file_path != patch.old_file_path:
                print '(was %s)' % patch.old_file_path,
            print

    if cur.parents:
        prev = cur
        cur = cur.parents[0]
```

If we run this against [a sample repository](http://github.com/larsks/heat-kubernetes), we can look at the
output for the first few commits:

```
c285a21e013892ee7601a53df16942cdcbd39fe6
D : fragments/configure-flannel.sh
A : fragments/flannel-config.service.yaml
A : fragments/write-flannel-config.sh
M : kubecluster.yaml
b06de8f2f366204aa1327491fff91574e68cd4ec
M : fragments/enable-services-master.sh
M : fragments/enable-services-minion.sh
c265ddedac7162c103672022633a574ea03edf6f
M : fragments/configure-flannel.sh
88a8bd0eefd45880451f4daffd47f0e592f5a62b
A : fragments/configure-docker-storage.sh
M : fragments/write-heat-params.yaml
M : kubenode.yaml
```

And compare that to the output of `git log --oneline --name-status`:

```
c285a21 configure flannel via systemd unit
D       fragments/configure-flannel.sh
A       fragments/flannel-config.service.yaml
A       fragments/write-flannel-config.sh
M       kubecluster.yaml
b06de8f call daemon-reload before starting services
M       fragments/enable-services-master.sh
M       fragments/enable-services-minion.sh
c265dde fix json syntax problem
M       fragments/configure-flannel.sh
88a8bd0 configure cinder volume for docker storage
A       fragments/configure-docker-storage.sh
M       fragments/write-heat-params.yaml
M       kubenode.yaml
```

...aaaand, that looks just about identical.  Hopefully this is enough
to you started.

Comment: Cool !  This will give me a way to check the files associated with the patch ! Really appreciate it. Where can I find detailed information about these things? As of now, I am referring the documentation and the search results. Thanks again!

Comment: I figured all of this out just now, reading through the [documentation](http://www.pygit2.org/) and fiddling around at the interactive Python prompt.  It was [this page](http://www.pygit2.org/diff.html#the-patch-type) that clued me in to how things might work.

Comment: The very last line `cur = cur.parents[0]` doesn't make sense to me, because `cur` will  be overwritten in the next `for` iteration. That would better go to the top of the loop. Then you don't miss the last diff, especially when using a walker for which hide() was called (i.e. walk a..b)

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly a rewrite of [larsks's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28389889/2311167) to

- the current pygit2 API
- Python3

It also fixes a flaw in the iteration logic: the original code would miss to diff the last revision against its parent when a revision range (a..b) is walked.

The following approximates the command

```sh
git log --name-status --pretty="format:Files changed in %h" origin/devel..master
```

on the sample repository given by larsks.

I was unable to trace file renames, though. This is printed as a deletion and an addition. The code line printing a rename is never reached.

```py
import pygit2

repo = pygit2.Repository('.')

# Show files changed between origin/devel and current HEAD
devel = repo.revparse_single('origin/devel')
walker = repo.walk(repo.head.target)
walker.hide(devel.id)

for cur in walker:
    if cur.parents:
        print (f'Files changed in {cur.short_id}')
        prev = cur.parents[0]

        diff = prev.tree.diff_to_tree(cur.tree)
        for patch in diff:
            print(patch.delta.status_char(), ':', patch.delta.new_file.path)
            if patch.delta.new_file.path != patch.delta.old_file.path:
                print(f'(was {patch.delta.old_file.path})'.)
        print()
```